# Reference letter in a .txt file

Tags: recommendation-letter

My supervisor wrote me a reference letter in *.txt* file with the following format:

> Reference for My Name
>
> --------------------------------
>
> Bla bla bla

Also no "Yours sincerely" with his name or anything.

Should I change it to a more conventional format or should I leave it as is?

Edit: I am sending open applications to research groups of interest and want to include a reference letter (not a recommendation letter)

Comment: What format is the institution to which you are applying requesting your references in? Many institutions will only accept references directly from your referee's institutional email address.

Comment: What are you supposed to do with that file? I doubt that it is up to you to format or send it. Could it be that your supervisor just sent it to you as a reference what they are going to write about you? In which case, I guess you supervisor would expect some feedback regarding the content, not the formating.

Comment: I am sending open applications to research groups of interest and want to include a reference letter (not a recommendation letter)

Comment: @user3209815 In many countries, it's the applicant who sends the letters, not the reference. See, e.g., [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/71440/20058) and the related question.